# Upgrade JunOS from 11.4R1.14 to 13.3R5.9 on MX-80

Tags: junos

I'm tried to upgrade from 11.4R1.14 to 13.3R5.9. Before upgrade I'm validate jinstall, but it's failed with message:

```
> request system software validate /var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-13.3R5.9-domestic-signed.tgz
...
Validating against /config/juniper.conf.gz
mgd: error: Check-out failed for Adaptive services process (/usr/sbin/spd) without details
mgd: error: configuration check-out failed
Validation failed
WARNING: Current configuration not compatible with /var/tmp/jinstall-ppc-13.3R5.9-domestic-signed.tgz
```

How I can resolve it? I would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in:

```
services adaptive-services-pics traceoptions flag all
```

and configured NAT, that not working if there is no DPC.